# Rundeck deployment

Tags: rundeck

I'm new to Rundeck and have a quick question about it.

Is there a way we can deploy to a single node successfully and pause it while we do the validation and resume after the successful validation to the rest of the nodes/tags in Rundeck?

Answer (score 0):

With a standard Rundeck installation with bundled plugins, I’m uncertain if that can be achieved. Would you mind sharing some details about your validation process? One plugin you could try is the [nixy-step-plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/nixy-step-plugins) ‘waitfor’ steps, as they can perform some validation based on; if a file contains a string, if a host is up using ping, a port is open, etc, before continuing with the next steps in a job’s execution. If that plugin alone is unable to fit your validation process, you could also create your own custom plugin using the nixy-step plugin as guidance alongside the [Plugin developer guide](http://rundeck.org/docs/developer/index.html).
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. It will be QA validation about the functionality of the application and some UA testing and this is manual today :). Is there anyway we can A/B kind of deployment, like from the list of nodes found, Rundeck has to pick 50% of it and deploy and then later other 50%. Is that possible?